# Notification area balloon tip pop sound in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, notification-area

When I was using Windows XP, there was a distinct sound when an application showed a balloon tip in the notification area (aka *system tray*). Unfortunately, I didn't look any deeper into it. Now Windows 7 has this behavior disabled by default and I do not know how to configure it.

---

Discovered the name of sound file used to accompany tray balloon tips in Windows XP `Windows XP Balloon.wav`

---

More clues: interesting registry key is `HKEY_USERS\XP Registry Hive\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemNotification\.Default`

Default value is `%SystemRoot%\media\Windows XP Balloon.wav`

So, the `System Notification` event label appears to be correct, but tray balloons are silenced elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound
- Click on Change System Sounds under the Sounds heading
- Under the Windows heading, tweak the System Notification item

Comment: System Notification sound event works, but tray ballons are remaining completely silent.

Comment: Hmmm, thought that was it.  Windows Balloon.wav is set to play on that item.  Let me check again.

Comment: @Worm This is definitely the one, at least for Windows balloon notifications - confirmed with low battery notification.  What notification is not sounding for you?

Comment: i'm affraid `low battery` notification have distinct sound event, and last time it worked ok. Other non-specific ballons like "low space" and "no antivirus" are silent

Comment: @Worm right... bad choice for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me (found on some MS forum):

1. In registry editor go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/AppEvents/Schemes/Explorer`
2. Under Explorer you shouldn't see `SystemNotification` entry, so it comes to next step.
3. Right click on Explorer -> New -> Key and rename it as `SystemNotification`
4. Right click on `SystemNotification` -> New -> Key and rename it as `.current`
5. Left click on `.current`, and in right panel you'll see `(Default)` entry, double click on it.
6. In value data paste `C:\Windows\media\Windows XP Balloon.wav` and click OK

NOTE: Obviously, you will have to copy the Windows XP Balloon WAV file to your Media folder for this to work exactly as shown above; just enter the path to your favorite balloon sound in step #6...

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the Ease of Access Center: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-accessibility-features-does-Windows-offer

You should be able to change your sound notification there.

Comment: Which exactly option i have to change there?